# Crear DLL y usarla, compilacion lenguaje C

Tags: c++, librería, exe, dll, g++

lei, esta pagina de microsoft, Creacion y uso de una biblioteca de vinculos dinamicos en C++
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms235636(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Esta pagina menciona como compilar un archivo cpp. y un .h para convertirla a un DLL
Luego menciona de un tercer archivo para poder utilizar esta esta DLL
Al final se tiene 2 archivos un .EXE que necesita de la .DLL para poder arrancar el programa.
En lugar de usar Visual Studio, use la linea de comandos para desarrolladores "CL.exe"

```
cl MathFuncsDll.cpp /EHsc /LD
```

Este comando se usa para tomar un .cpp y .h para, crear un objeto un .lib para luego convertirla en una DLL

```
cl MyExecRefsDll.cpp /EHsc /link MathFuncsDll.lib
```

Este comando compila el archivo .cpp crea un ejecutable y une el ejecutable con la DLL.

Ahora mi pregunta ¿es como podria hacer lo mismo con la aplicacion MinGW que tiene el compilador gcc y g++? Es decir primero tomar MathFuncsDll.cpp y MathFuncsDll.h para crear un archivo .obj .lib y un dll.
Luego MyExecRefsDll.cpp, crea un ejecutable que use las bibliotecas ya creadas.

Comment: Seguramente puedes generar un DLL con gcc, pero la librería estática tendrá el nombre **lib<lo que sea>.a**.

Comment: Pero como es la sintaxis para crear la dll y linkear el ejecutable

Comment: Si te apañas con el inglés esta pagina te puede ayudar: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84461/MinGW-Static-and-Dynamic-Libraries